# Linking tumblr photos directly to the source

Tags: html, tumblr

I'm trying to make my tumblr posts link directly to the source when clicked rather than going to the post page and having the source link there to click.

Here's the code I have for the photo posts.

`{block:Photo}
            <div class="permalink"><a href="{Permalink}">{MonthNumber}.{DayOfMonthWithZero}.{ShortYear}</a></div>
                <div class="photo">
                    <div class="photobox"><a href="{Permalink}"><img src="{PhotoURL-250}" alt="{PhotoAlt}"/></a></div>
                    {block:Caption}
                        <div class="caption">{Caption}</div>
                    {/block:Caption}
                </div>
            {/block:Photo}`

I've tried changing the photobox 'permalink' to source etc with no avail.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*after comments edit*

It should be `<a href="{LinkURL}">`

You have to make sure when you're adding the image that you've specified the target as outside of tumblr too.

[image]

Comment: Hi Josh, I've tried the above and that just links back to my URL. The URL is www.bebrisk.co.uk

Comment: Thats because your `href` is empty on view source: `<div class="photobox"><a href=""><img src="http://...jpg" alt=""/></a></div>` How are you adding these images, standard tumblr dashboard style? Or manually?

Comment: I'm adding them through the tumblr dashboard - you can see that i've included the links here? - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/227304/Screenshots/0v.png

Comment: No Worries. I'll edit the answer then you can mark it as correct? :-)

Answer (score 1):

In the hope that someone who needs this will find it, here's a way I found to show `{LinkURL}` when it's available, and some other url when it's not.

---

Tumblr offers `{block:LinkURL}` to display some code **when `{LinkURL}` is available**, but there's no `{block:NoLinkURL}` to use **when `{LinkURL}` is NOT available.**

Ideally, this should be possible:

```
<a 
{block:LinkURL}href="{LinkURL}"{/block:LinkURL}
{block:NoLinkURL}href="{Permalink}"{/block:NoLinkURL}> <!-- does NOT work -->
    <img src="{PhotoURL-400}"/>
</a>
```

But `{block:NoLinkURL}` doesn't exist, so I'm using `{block:LinkURL}` to hijack the normal link instead:

```
<a {block:LinkURL} href="{LinkURL}" data-ignored-{/block:LinkURL}href="{Permalink}">
    <img src="{PhotoURL-400}"/>
</a>
```

If `{LinkURL}` is available both links will be in the HTML, but only one is read.

## Example output

This is the output **when `{LinkURL}` is not available:**

```
<a href="/permalink">
    <img src="/image.jpg"/>
</a>
```

And this when is the output **when `{LinkURL}` is available:**

```
<a href="/linkurl" data-ignored-href="/permalink">
    <img src="/image.jpg"/>
</a>
```